# Query Wikidata to get all properties that are subclasses of entity (all types of images associated with an entity)

Tags: sparql, wikidata

My goal is to get all images related to a wikidata entity. I can get the image property (of e.g. the statue of liberty) with the following query:

```
SELECT ?image WHERE
{
    wd:Q9202 wdt:P18 ?image.
}
```

This gets me the associated image but there are many types of image properties (P14, P15, P18, P41,...). They are all types of ["Wikidata property for linking to a representative image (Q26940804)"](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q26940804).

Is there an elegant way to get all properties that are subclasses of `Q26940804` (getting all images)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truthy predicates, which start with `wdt:P`, are connected to `wd:Q26940804` not directly, but through their prototypic properties, which start with `wd:P`.

```
SELECT ?predicate ?propertyLabel ?image WHERE
{
    wd:Q9202 ?predicate ?image .
    ?property wikibase:directClaim ?predicate .
    ?property wdt:P31 wd:Q26940804
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

[Try it!](https://w.wiki/7$xa)

More info:

- [RDF Dump Format § Properties](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Properties)
- [RDF Dump Format § Predicates](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Predicates)

Also, those `wd:P18` etc. are instances of `wd:Q26940804`, not subclasses.